# How to iterate over buffers in Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, buffers

How can I iterate over the current open buffers and say, load the buffer numbers into an array in vimscript?

I know there exists arrays or similar data structures in vimscript.
I know that every buffer gets assigned a unique number.
My goal is to put each of those numbers into an array of the same length as   the number of buffers i.e   `for i in number of open buffers: array[i] = #buffer`
I would like to let `array` be a variable in my vimscript file.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Have you read the doc ([`:h :ls`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Als), [`:h buffer-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#buffer%2Dlist), [`:h :bnext`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abnext), [`:h buffers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#buffers))? What are you trying to actually do? I think you question would benefit from a bit more of details.

Comment: @statox iterating with `:bnext` is an extremely cumbersome solution -- see my answer. Otherwise, indeed, as usual with vim one has to read the doc as (almost) everything in present in it. However in this case, several elements are to be combined. We need to be familiar with a dozen entries from `:h functions` and with `:h List`.

Comment: @statox I don't know vimscript and I was hoping for a quick answer. I don't know how it could be more clear what I was trying to do. Did you downvote my question because it wasn't clear enough? I will edit it for you.

Comment: @LucHermitte I agree that the `:bnext` isn't the way to go and that the solution is not exactly straight forward. I was just pointing out that it is often a good idea to show a minimum of research in a question: this way answerers feel like they're helping and not only doing some work because OP was to lazy to do it. @lsund: I did not downvoted you (I tend to avoid downvoting new users's questions without a very good reason) I was just inviting you to provide more details about what you already researched :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can iterate over buffers if you use `:bnext` and all. I highly advice against this method. It'll trigger autocommands, and you'll have to remember where you were. In other words, it can be damn slow, and with plenty side effects. Stay away if you can.

Until now my preferred approach was to use `filter()` on `range(1, bufnr('$'))` to keep the buffers I'm interested in (`bufloaded()`, `bufexists()` or `buflisted()`). Which gives:

```
:let buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')
```

We can even go further and use other ways to filter the buffer list: according to their name, or buffer-variables (.e.g `getbufvar(v:val, 'foo', sentinelvalue) =~ "regex for b:foo")`).

As you see, there are plenty options. The entry points are `filter()` and functions with `buf` in their name -> `:h *buf*()^D` (`^D` as in *hit ctrl+D* to see the list of functions)

Note also that recent versions of vim provide a new `getbufinfo()` function that'll return a list dictionaries: each dictionary is filled with plenty information for each existing buffer. Another way to obtain existing buffers is with:

```
:let buffers = map(copy(getbufinfo()), 'v:val.bufnr')
```

Or listed buffers with

```
:let buffers = map(filter(copy(getbufinfo()), 'v:val.listed'), 'v:val.bufnr')
```

Comment: I guess that `E117: Unknown function: getbufinfo` means my vim doesn't have this, correct?

Comment: @qneill. Indeed, you'll have to revert to older functions, or to upgrade your version of vim.

Comment: I see some weird behavior, these maps/filters don't give same results. The last one in your description seems accurate, it returns the buffers I as a user am aware of, and matches result of command ``:buffers``, and able to open with ``:b <number>`` to find some information in. Rest all the commands give varying degrees of extra buffer numbers.

Comment: @reportaman The buffers can be in various states whether they are displayed, unloaded, wiped out, and so on. Some commands already filter out the useless ones.

Comment: Not sure if it was implemented from start (i.e. when answr was written), but `getbufinfo` also accept a filter e.g: `getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1})` - so `map(getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}), 'v:val.bufnr')` - as in no need for `filter()`

Comment: @user3342816 Answer was written in 2016 ;) But, I've missed the fact it could filter on the fly from the start.

Answer (score 7):

On neovim additionally to `getbufinfo()` one can also use

```
let buffers = nvim_list_bufs()
```

[nvim_list_bufs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_list_bufs())