# vim: count how many buffers been modified?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, statusline, counting

Pursuing a vimscript function or expression that

count how many buffers been modified.

i.e., how many buffers `:bm` could switch to,

given that option `hidden` is set.

**== Edit ==**

In the hope of used in `statusline`.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

```
func! CountModifiedBuffer()
    let mod = map(getbufinfo(), 'v:val.changed')
    return len(filter(mod, 'v:val'))
endfunc
```

**== Edit ==**

I use `%{IsBuffersModified()}` instead of builtin `%m` inside my `statusline` setting, which encode more info.

```
" [+] if only current modified, [+3] if 3 modified including current buffer.
" [3] if 3 modified and current not, "" if none modified.
func! IsBuffersModified()
    let cnt = CountModifiedBuffer()
    return cnt == 0 ? "" : ( &modified ? "[+". (cnt>1?cnt:"") ."]" : "[".cnt."]" )
endfunc
```

**== Edit Edit ==**

`CountModifiedBuffer` could be one-liner.

```
    return len(filter(getbufinfo(), 'v:val.changed == 1'))
```

Comment: know `getbufinfo` from https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10478/10254

Comment: NB: `getbufinfo` is deprecated. Use `getbufvar` instead. Example: `getbufvar(0, "&mod")`

Comment: @BradenBest, where have you read about `getbufinfo()` deprecation?

Comment: @LucHermitte This was over two months ago, so I don't remember the source. At the time, I was modifying a vim script that was using `getbufinfo` to render the buffers in the tab bar, and either through vim telling me directly, or a source online that said to use `getbufvar`, I found out that `getbufinfo` has been deprecated. I'm trying to test `getbufinfo` in vim right now and not only is it not working at all, but I can't find a single shred of documentation on it. `:h getbufinfo` -> nothing; `:h getbufvar` -> help page. So even if the source was wrong, `getbufvar` is clearly more reliable.

Comment: @LucHermitte Vim documentation in the online space is pretty sparse, but from what I can gather, it seems that getbufinfo was introduced in 8.x, whereas I (and anyone on an APT repo) am using 7.4. If this is correct, then `getbufinfo` has yet to reach market saturation, and you should default to `getbufvar` or a polyfill **in order to keep vim plugins portable**.

Comment: I'd check tomorrow on a fresh install of 8.1.02x or so. There is an entry behind `:h getbufinfo()`. If I remember correctly it's quite recent. Much more recent than `getbufvar()`. So indeed, `getbufvar()`  is to be preferred for  portability reasons. But not because the other one has been deprecated. According to [git blame](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/0b6d911e5de1a1c10a23d4c2ee1b0275c474a2dd/runtime/doc/usr_41.txt), `getbufinfo()` appears in v7.4.2204 and `getbufvar()` in v7.0c13.