# Run autocommand only after all buffers have been written using :wa

Tags: buffers, autocmd

I use an `autocmd` to copy a directory using `rsync` when saving a file with `BufWritePost`.
When I save multiple files at once (using `:wa`), it runs `rsync` after every buffer save.

How can I run `rsync` or the `autocmd` only after all files have been written?

Comment: The only reasonable thing I can think of is something like `VimLeave` or other exiting commands, which is not really what you asked for.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the response! I tried making the `autocmd` conditional on the number of buffers to be written, but I couldn't find a way to do that. Do you know how to get the number of unsaved buffers?

Comment: Check how many are `&modified`, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I managed to do this by checking the number of modified buffers.
Once the number of buffers reaches 0, only then run rsync.

```
func! CountModifiedBuffer()
  " See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14313/40380
  return len(filter(getbufinfo(), 'v:val.changed == 1'))
endfunc

augroup project
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost path/to/project/*
        \ if CountModifiedBuffer() == 0
        \ | execute "!rsync -avu src dest | grep -v .git/"
        \ | endif
augroup END
```