# How can I determine if *any* window in the current tabpage is in diff-mode?

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, vimdiff

So, I found [this useful answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10478/6108) about iterating *buffers*; but due to the tabpage-specific duality of windows in Vim, I failed at adapting it to my needs.

Thus: how can I construct a boolean expression, determining whether or not *any* (not just the current) window in the tabpage is in `&diff`-mode?

Answer (score 7):

You can sum up the values of `&diff` for each window, and see if the total is > 0:

```
let any_diff = 0
windo let any_diff += &diff
echo any_diff . ' windows in diff mode'
if any_diff > 0 | do stuff | endif
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't like using `windo`  that could trigger events if done without any caution, and thus I prefer using programmatic ways instead.

For instance, we can obtain the window numbers of the windows in diff mode with

```
:echo filter(range(1, winnr('$')), 'getwinvar(v:val, "&diff") == 1')
```